# JavaScript/PHP problems with load in browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, browser

i have code that contain **JAVASCRIPT** code, so when i save the file that contain **jquery** code as js file, it run successfully.
But when restart my computer or close the project and return to it, i edit the code in js file but no change happen.
Only the change happen when i save another file with different name and include it again in my project.
So where is the problem?
I have this problem before with css, so i disabled the cache from the browser and run successfully.
thanks.

Comment: Cashing problem, if it's not your browser it's probably your web server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is impossible to tell what exactly you are asking. May you please include the relevant code to clarify this more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of browser cache.Add time stamp in script and link tag.
example here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?<?php echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))?>">
```

Here because of timestamp its load every time new.